# Parse String java

Tags: java, parsing

I have the following strings:

```
[19.47690987, -71.344714339999996]  6   2011-08-28 19:02:30 @Ninosh_Flow Jajajaj mi hermanasoooo
[35.106754240000001, -92.455415599999995]   6   2011-08-28 19:02:30 Your always on my mind
[40.973435600000002, -73.826951690000001]   6   2011-08-28 19:02:30 #nothingwrongwith having high standards...
```

I want to parse it like:

Coordinates: `[19.47690987, -71.344714339999996]`

Date: `2011-08-28`

Time: `19:02:30`

Line: `@Ninosh_Flow Jajajaj mi hermanasoooo`

What is the best way to do that ?
I have over 100 000 such lines?

I ve tried different variants with .split

```
line.split(" 6 ")[0], line.split(" ")[3], line.split(" ")[4], line.split(" ")[5])
```

I guess it's not what i rly need

Comment: Please show your attempt with your question.

Comment: Build a regex and implement it in Java. You could try here : https://regex101.com/

Comment: Use regular expressions.  It should be easy to find a tutorial.

Comment: You can definitely do this using the **String.split()** method. The trick would be to clean up the string somewhat first as towards excessive white-spaces and perhaps tabs. You can use the **String.replaceAll()** method for this, for example: `myString = dataString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").replaceAll("\\t", " ");`. Now split the String: `String[] data = myString.split("\\s");` Your coordinates will be held in array elements located at index 0 and 1, the date will be located at array index 3 and time at index 4. The comment in the string will be from index 5 to end of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
File myFile = new File("path-to-my-file");
Scanner scn = new Scanner(myFile);

while (scn.hasNextLine()) {
    scn.useDelimiter("\\]");
    String coord = scn.next() + "]";
    scn.useDelimiter("\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
    scn.next();  // Throw away ] delim
    scn.next();  // Throw away junk between coord and date
    String date = scn.next();
    String time = scn.next();
    String line = scn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Coodinates: " + coord);
    System.out.println("Date: " + date);
    System.out.println("Time: " + time);
    System.out.println("Line: " + line);
}
```

Comment: Much thanks! That what i was looking for)